# How Facebook put sale tag on apps' icon

Tags: facebook

I'd like to get same tag for my app, but I don't know how Facebook give this to apps.

[image]

[image]

You can see the tag above.

I thought it's given with payer promotion but I'm not sure. How can I achieve this to be put for my app?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a test we are doing and we are contacting the apps that we do this on. If we haven't contacted you you can't do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last thing I wonder is that we have some game with huge traffic in our country and we already have someone from facebook we contact frequently for these games. If we reach this person, can we get this trial somehow ?